# Is it possible to calculate a shipping price based on how many different values for a product attribute exist in the shopping cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

This may seem a somewhat strange question, but I'm going to ask anyway. I'm currently building a Magento store (CE 1.9) for a client who has an unusual requirement for shipping price calculation.

I need to be able to calculate a shipping price based on how many different values there are for a given product attribute, set within the products contained in the shopping cart, as part of the normal checkout process.

My first thought was that table rate might solve this, however I cannot find a way to achieve the desired result.

I'll try to explain what I need...

- Shipping on the site would use a 'base' shipping price of £6.95.
- The contents of the shopping cart would be reviewed and a list of all 'manufacturer' product attributes would be made, from which all duplicate values would be removed.
- The base price would then be multiplied by the number of values in the 'manufacturer' attribute list.

For example, if there were 4 values in the attribute list, the shipping cost would be £27.80.

Any advice on how this could be achieved would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Paul

Answer (score 2):

In short: yes it's possible but no there isn't a module or quick fix for this. I would recommend you follow this [Inchoo tutorial on shipping methods](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/) to set up your own method and from there use the quote objects item collection:

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

to build a calculation for the shipping costs.

If you run into any specific issues feel free to post another question. Always include code snippets and error logs if it concerns an error.